# Invisible checkbox, radio and input outlines CSS issue or what?

Tags: css

I have deployed LWCs with checkboxes, radio and lightning inputs to production in Salesforce experience cloud and suddenly their outlines are not visible. I have attached the two resulting outputs.

I can select and input but I need the outlines to be visible. The are working fine in the sandbox.

Could it be anything to do with styling and how would I resolve it? Any help is appreciated.

The CSS for the top component with the textbox is shown below

```
    .lgc-bg {
        background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    }
    
    .lgc-bg-inverse {
        background-color: rgb(22, 50, 92);
    }
    .search{
        padding-left: 1cm;
        padding-right: 1cm;
        
        
    }
    h2{
        font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        font-size: medium;
        padding-bottom: -0.5cm;
        padding-left: 0.5cm;
    }
    .button{
        margin-top: 0.27cm;
        
    }
    .template{
        border: white;
    }
```

The html

```
    <template>
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium" >
      
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_5-of-6 slds-p-bottom_large">
                <h2>Search Community Engagements</h2>
               <h3><lightning-input type="search"  onchange={handleChange} class="search" placeholder="Enter a search term" data-name="reset"></lightning-input></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-6 slds-p-top_x-large button" >    
                    <lightning-button label=" Search " onclick={handleSearch} variant="brand" ></lightning-button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small"></p>
            <p slot="footer">
               
            </p>
            <template if:true={error}>
                <c-error-panel errors={error}></c-error-panel>
            </template>
        
    </div>
    </template>
```

The component with the checkboxes

```
<template>
    
        <h1>Refine your search </h1>
        <h2><a href="#" onclick={clearAllFilters} >Clear all filters</a> </h2>

        <lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup"         
            options={radoptions}
            value={value}
            class="radio"            
            type="radio"
            checked={checked}
            onchange={handleRadio}>
        </lightning-radio-group>
  

        <h2>Issues Area</h2>
        
        <template if:true={issueAreas.data}>
            
            <lightning-checkbox-group name="issueArea"
                            
                    class="card"
                    options={issueAreas.data.values}                   
                    value={issueAreas.data.values}  
                    onchange={handleIssueAreas}
                    checked={checked}>
                </lightning-checkbox-group>
                           
          
        </template>
         
        <h2>SLCC Department</h2>

        <lightning-checkbox-group name="departments"
            options={deptoptions}
            value={value}
            class="card"
            onchange={handleDepartment}>
       </lightning-checkbox-group>


        <h2>Engagement Type</h2>
        <template if:true={engagements.data}>
            
            <lightning-checkbox-group name="engagements"
                            
                    class="card"
                    
                    options={engagements.data.values}                   
                    value={engagements.data.values}  
                    onchange={handleEngagements}
                    checked={checked}>
                </lightning-checkbox-group>
                           
          
        </template>
        
        <h2>Location</h2>

        <template if:true={cities.data}>
            
            <lightning-checkbox-group name="location"
                            
                    class="card"
                    options={cities.data.values}                   
                    value={cities.data.values}  
                    onchange={handleCities}
                    checked={checked}>
                </lightning-checkbox-group>

        </template>

        <h2>Ages Served</h2>
        <template if:true={population.data}>
            
            <lightning-checkbox-group name="population"
                            
                    class="card"
                    options={population.data.values}                   
                    value={population.data.values}  
                    onchange={handlePopulation}
                    checked={checked}>
                </lightning-checkbox-group>
                           
          
        </template>

        <h2>Partner Type</h2>
        <template if:true={partners.data}>
            
            <lightning-checkbox-group name="engagements"
                            
                    class="card"
                    options={partners.data.values}                   
                    value={partners.data.values}  
                    onchange={handlePartners}
                    checked={checked}>
                </lightning-checkbox-group>                           
          
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}>
            <c-error-panel errors={error}></c-error-panel>
        </template>
       
   
</template>
```

CSS..

```
.card{   
    padding: 0.5cm;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
}
h2{
    font-size:14px;
    color:navy;
    padding-left: 0.5cm;
}
.radio{
  color:royalblue;
  padding-left: 0.5cm;
  padding-bottom: 0.3cm;
}
h1{
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 0.3cm;
}
```

Production output.
[image: production]

sandbox output
[image: sandbox]

Comment: Can't really help images are supplemental, code is essential post HTML and CSS as a [mcve].

Comment: I have added the code.